# Erro em leitura de XML

Tags: c#

Estou querendo ler nós de um XML e meu código abaixo está gerando exceção:

```
XmlDocument arquivo = new XmlDocument();

arquivo.Load(@"Z:\Área de Trabalho\Windows XP.xml");

// Esta linha abaixo gera a exceção
// "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

XmlNodeList lista = arquivo.SelectSingleNode("VirtualBox").SelectSingleNode("Machine").
SelectSingleNode("MediaRegistry").SelectSingleNode("HardDisks").ChildNodes;

foreach (XmlNode item in lista)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Attributes["uuid"]);
}
```

O link do XML é este [Windows XP.xml](http://1drv.ms/1Hnwma5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifiquei um pouco seu código para o seguinte:

```
        XmlDocument arquivo = new XmlDocument();

        arquivo.Load(@"D:\Downloads\Windows XP.xml");

        // Esta linha abaixo gera a exceção
        // "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

        var lista = arquivo.SelectSingleNode("VirtualBox"); 
        var lista2 = lista.SelectSingleNode("Machine")
            .SelectSingleNode("MediaRegistry")
            .SelectSingleNode("HardDisks")
            .ChildNodes;

        foreach (XmlNode item in lista)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Attributes["uuid"]);
        }
```

`lista` já vem nulo. Significa que a seleção falha já nele:

```
var lista = arquivo.SelectSingleNode("VirtualBox");
```

Como o XML tem um *namespace* definido, o recomendável é usar um [`XmlNamespaceManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) para ler corretamente o nó:

```
        arquivo.Load(@"D:\Downloads\Windows XP.xml");
        var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(arquivo.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("vbox", "http://www.innotek.de/VirtualBox-settings");
```

Assim sendo, todas as leituras sobsequentes precisam considerar o *namespace*. Meu código final ficou assim, funcionando:

```
        XmlDocument arquivo = new XmlDocument();

        arquivo.Load(@"D:\Downloads\Windows XP.xml");
        var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(arquivo.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("vbox", "http://www.innotek.de/VirtualBox-settings");

        var lista = arquivo.SelectSingleNode("//vbox:VirtualBox", nsmgr);
        var lista2 = arquivo.SelectSingleNode("//vbox:Machine", nsmgr);
        var lista3 = lista2.SelectSingleNode("//vbox:MediaRegistry", nsmgr).SelectSingleNode("//vbox:HardDisks", nsmgr).ChildNodes;

        foreach (XmlNode item in lista2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Attributes["uuid"]);
        }
```